Is there a way to get separate N and % columns using gtsummary and flextable?
I am making a descriptive table of categorical variables. gtsummary::tbl_summary combined with as_flextable and my own flextable adjustments gives me the APA-formatted table I want, with frequencies and percentages.
However, I would like indices to be in separate columns.
I have been looking for ways to adapt this code to get separate N and % columns instead of N (%)
trial2 <- gtsummary::trial |> dplyr::select(trt, age, grade)
trial2 |> gtsummary::tbl_summary() %>% gtsummary::as_flex_table()
Any suggestions?

You can use tbl_wide_summary(). https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_wide_summary.html
trial |>
  tbl_wide_summary(include = c(response, grade)



Thank you, this is exactly what I've been looking for. Is it possible to control the decimals of the percentage?

Yes, check out the help file for the function and review the digits argument. tbl_wide_summary(trial, include = c(response, grade), digits = ~ c(0,1))

Thank you! It seems that in digits, I am only able to select variables in my data, and not the summarised columns:
trial |>
tbl_wide_summary(include = c(response, grade), digits = "%"~2)
Column % doesn't exist.
Select among columns "response" and "grade"

I am confused. Did you see the code in the above comment with the digits example?

Indeed, I was confused - thank you!
